# How to use SSL for some pages and not for others?

Tags: ssl

We are building an application where we want anything the following to be SSL:

secure.ourapp.com -> all pages must be SSL (can this be done with a Vhost in apache?)

www.ourapp.com/signup -> SSL
www.ourapp.com/login -> SSL
www.ourapp.com/information -> NOT SSL

So my question is: can you put SSL on some pages and not on others? Or does it only work on a per-subdomain basis?

thanks a lot for helping me out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, with some caveats.

The 2 SSL hosts will need different public IP addresses for maximum compatibility.  There is name based SSL, but Apache [doesn't support](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html) that.

There's nothing stopping you supporting SSL for all pages on the main site and simply using `SSLRequireSSL` for the relevant `/login` area to deny access without SSL.  Then you can simply direct people to `https://` from the signup page and back to `http://` when leaving the login page.

If you want to get a little fancier you could use the re-write options to redirect people who connect using the "wrong" protocol.  I do something like that with Lighttpd.

---

Yes.  You need 2 certificates and then use the SSLRequireSSL option for the parts you want to protect with SSL.  I'd suggest that using a [rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/) is kinder on visitors than simply denying access to HTTP connections to /signup in particular.  See [this page](http://www.whoopis.com/howtos/apache-rewrite.html) for an example of how to do that.

Comment: Re: name-based SSL (TLS), Apache *does* support this in recent versions via SNI - See http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/NameBasedSSLVHostsWithSNI . For maximum compatibility you should still have separate IPs for each SSL vhost though...

Comment: Interesting, thanks.  None of their core documentation mentions this.

Comment: thanks! So do you mean that we should do the following:

1. set up SSL certificate for www.app.com and only requireSSL for /signup and /login (these are not directories but php controllers)

2. set up another SSL certificate for secure.app.com ?